# Chart назначить оси в коде программы

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Имеется База данных, расположенная в определенной директории (допустим, P:\Pr1\database.mdb). На форму добавлен элемент chart, хочу построить диаграмму по элементам своей БД. Пробовал подключать и выводить данные через окно свойства элемента управления диаграммы,добавляя новый источник данных, после чего в свойствах XValueMember и YValueMember выставляя нужные мне поля. Хотел попробовать реализовать это в коде, для этого подключил бд к элементу chart:

```
chart1.DataSource=@"P:\Pr1\database.mdb";
```

Подскажите, можно ли так обратиться к свойствам XValueMember и YValueMember и задать им значения непосредственно в коде и как это сделать, через IntelliSense не смог найти эти свойства.

Comment: Когда Вы правите свойства элемента в дизайнере Visual Studio обычно создается файл `[Имяформы].designer.cs` в котором прописывается код, соответствующий изменениям. Можно его изучить или просто скопировать. Еще, проставьте метку используемой графической платформы: winforms, WPF, ASP или что-то другое?

Comment: @defaultlocale спасибо за совет, попробую! Метку добавил.

Comment: не, так не получится, получите из БД интересующие вас данные, обычным способом, через ADO или любой другой фреймворк. После этого можете передать в DataSource объект типа Enumerable<T>, List<T> или возможно DataTable (последнее сам не пробовал), тогда должен подтянуть данные автоматом. А сейчас вы ему передали в качестве источника данных обычную строку, и более чем логично, что он из нее ни чего полезного извлечь не смог.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456766.aspx#%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85 вот это еще почитайте